# "Please install lmxl if you want to use 'options' class", what does this mean?

Tags: python, lxml, py2exe

To use pandas lib, I make a simple python program.

It works well when I run the `*.py` file. After I pack all the files into a exe with py2exe, I double click the exe to run it, then I get a message in the command line window:

> `Please install lxml if you want to use 'options' class.`

Does it mean `lxml` lib is not packed into my exe correctly? Anyone know how to solve the problem?

My `setup.py` is:

```
from distutils.core import setup
import py2exe
setup(console=['app.py'],
options={
      'py2exe': {
              'includes': ['lxml.etree',
                           'lxml._elementpath', 
                           'numexpr'],
                }
        }
)
```

Then the new problem comes:numexpr not found. cannot use engine = numexpr for query/eval if numexpr is not installed.

Comment: What is your `setup.py`? Do you include `lxml` in the dependencies?

Comment: @PeterWood I changed my setup.py into follows, from distutils.core import setup
import py2exe
   
setup(
    console=['app.py'],
    options={
        'py2exe': 
        {
            'includes': ['lxml.etree', 'lxml._elementpath', 'numexpr'],
        }
    }
), when i run app.exe, the above error disappears this time, but new error comes: numexpr not found. cannot use engine = numexpr for query/eval if numexpr is not installed.

Comment: Modify you question please. Comments do not support code formatting.

Comment: Make sure numexpr is installed, it sounds like it's not.